# Unreliable Query results from an Access DB with a PHP PDO odbc connection using the MDBTools driver

Tags: php, pdo, mdbtools

I'm on a Ubuntu 16.04 box, and have connected to an MS Access database via PHP PDO. I am using the MDBTools odbc driver. To prepare for this, I ran the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install php7.0-odbc
sudo apt install libmdbodbc1
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbccr.so.2 /etc/libodbccr.so
```

**I can connect to the database just fine**. Connection example:

```
$driver = 'MDBTools';
$accdb  = '/var/www/html/access/mydb.accdb';
$dbh = new PDO('odbc:DRIVER=' . $driver . '; DBQ=' . $accdb);
```

First query:

```
// See a whole record
foreach( $dbh->query('
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM Assets
    WHERE Asset_ID = 12
', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row )
{
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump( $row );
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Results of first query:

```
array(7) {
  ["Asset_ID"]=>
  string(2) "12"
  ["Asset_Date"]=>
  string(17) "10/07/16 00:00:00"
  ["Asset_Category"]=>
  NULL
  ["Asset_SubCategory1"]=>
  NULL
  ["Asset_Spot_X"]=>
  NULL
  ["Asset_Spot_Y"]=>
  NULL
  ["Asset_Spot_Z"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Notice that in the first query, many of the fields are showing that the values are NULL, but this isn't actually the way it is in the database. I'll show you in the second query:

```
// See same record's Asset_Spot_X value
foreach( $dbh->query('
    SELECT 
        Asset_Spot_X 
    FROM Assets
    WHERE Asset_ID = 12
', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row )
{
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump( $row );
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Results for second query:

```
array(1) {
  ["Asset_Spot_X"]=>
  string(4) "1252"
}
```

These queries are run at the same time, so the value for Asset_Spot_X should be the same, but in one I get NULL, and in the other I get 1252. What am I doing wrong? It seems like the queries that I'm doing are really simple, so I don't understand what's going on. PDO isn't showing any errors when I check for errorInfo and errorCode.

Comment: @Parfait, I already did that, and the result is the same.

Comment: How many rows have `Asset_ID = 12`? Run a `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` to confirm.

Comment: @Parfait ,  It seems strange, it won't let me do that query: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Assets WHERE Asset_ID = 12`. That query returns FALSE, not an array. But there is only one row where Asset_ID is 12.

Comment: Indeed that is strange. I wonder if its incompatibility of the current Access .accdb types vs older .mdb types which module was developed using. What Access version is this: 2007/2010/2013/2016? Try saving it as older version: 2003.

Comment: I don't know about the incompatibility. I can't save the file as anything newer, because I don't have the version of Access that allows one to do such things. I only have the free version of Access, and not really wanting to give Microsoft $100.00.

Comment: I mention incompatibility because mdbtools was built using the older Access engine, specifically Jet 3/4. Older Access files were .mdb versions (i.e., the name) and not the current .accdb using ACE 12.0 engine. See this [repo issue](https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools/issues/77) of Access 2013 version not quite working right. You are passing correct SQL.

Comment: Well, thanks for your time. This work isn't critical. Just wanted to see if I could do it, as I tried before and failed, so I thought i'd give it another shot. For a few months I've been converting an old Access app into a PHP/MySQL app. The Access app is done up with a bunch of C or VB macros (or something like that). Pretty weird project. Every so often the project manager sends me a new accdb file, and I have to import the data, which up until yesterday I've been doing in a pretty painful way. Yesterday I found access2csv, and from the CSV I can import quite easily. Anyways, thanks again.

Comment: If you have access to a Windows machine, you can easily work with accdb files via code including PHP. The MS Office program is only the GUI console but the database (JET/ACE engine) are Windows .dll files installed on all PC machines. So you can use .mdb/.accdb without MSAccess.exe installed. But that is only for the db tables/stored queries not the VBA modules which the GUI .exe is needed.